# form has both a `name` attribute and a `ng-controller` directive?

Tags: angularjs

I understand that a `form` directive is an instance of `FormController` and is published onto the current scope under the value of the `name` attribute. (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).
What happens then when a `form` directive also contains a `ng-controller` directive as shown in [this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)?

I tried to see what would happen if the name of the `ng-controller` attribute is not "FormController":

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='angular.js'></script>
  </head>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   Object.prototype.getName = function() { 
     var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
     var results = (funcNameRegex).exec((this).constructor.toString());
     return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
   };
  </script>
  <body>
    <div ng-app='theApp'>
      <form name='myForm' >
      </form>
      {{myForm.getName()}}
      <form name='myForm2' ng-controller='MyFormController'>
        {{myForm2.getName()}}
      </form>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     angular.module('theApp', []).controller('MyFormController', ['$scope', function($scope) {}]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code prints in the console:

```
FormController
FormController
```

Comment: ng-controller is just a directive, as well as ng-form. Obviously you can define more than one directive on element. Each directive may have controller. What's the problem?

Comment: why would you need to add `ng-controller` on form itself anyway? Would make more sense adding it to it's parent. Really not clear what the problem is either way

Comment: @charlietfl attaching an `ng-controller on the form itself is what's shown as example in the documentation of the form directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Comment: ok, well don't confuse the two. You would use the `ng-controller` to manage your code ... data model, submit code etc. The `myForm2` object will also be set on it's scope

Answer (score 0):

The name of the controller is not important!

The sense of `ngForm` is that a `<form>` automatically becomes an instance of the `ngForm` directive, to which you can attach any controller!

So in the end your `myForm2` will have:

- `ngForm` methods and props (es. myForm2.$valid ecc.)
- `MyFormController` methods and props (in your case... nothing :-p )